# Is the linear operator $T(f)(x) = f(-x) + f(x)$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

My understanding is that the inverse of a linear operator will effectively "undo" the operation.

Therefore to get the inverse of this operator we need to somehow subtract the f(-x).

But I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$. Then $Tf=0$ and also $Tg=0$.

Comment: If $f$ is any odd function, $f(x) = - f(-x)$, then $T(f)(x) = 0$.

Comment: Let $g$ be defined by $g(x)=f(-x)$. We have $T(f)=T(g)$ but $f$ and $g$ may be different.

Comment: What is the domain and target of $T$?